# An overview of mathematical-logical approaches in formalizing natural languages

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, type-theory, formal-languages, lambda-calculus

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4747676) on Mathematics SE</sub>

---

I am an undergraduate mathematics student with a keen interest in pursuing research in the formalization of natural languages (from a more mathematical-logical approach), yet there aren't many resources that provide an overview of this very technical field. I wish to be able to provide myself a general map to navigate this subject more clearly, so I will attempt to explain my basic understanding of an overview of the fields that tackle with this subject, and I'd greatly appreciate any correction or addition to my limited insight.

From my understanding, (loosely speaking) there are two prominent mathematical-logical approaches in formalizing natural languages: Categorial Grammar and Montague Semantics. While Categorial Grammar uses methods borrowed from category theory to (mainly) study the syntax of natural languages, Montague Semantics, as the name might suggest, (mainly) focuses on the semantics of natural languages by implementing methods from Lambda Calculus. In terms of subareas of each of these two fields, I have not seen much discussed in terms of the subareas of Montague Semantics; however, Categorial Grammar seems ripe with subareas (although I have heard some of the fields mentioned below are only closely related to Categorial Grammar rather than being a strict subfield of it):

1. Combinatory Categorial Grammar (CCG)
2. Lambek Calculus
3. Type-Logical Grammar
4. Pre-Group Grammar
5. Proof-Theoretic Semantics

In addition to any corrections or additions, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for resources, references or books that deal with these subjects or their prerequisites

Comment: Why the vote to Close? I am continually appalled by the  persistent hostility n MathOverflow to anyone who sees mathematics outside the 1950s bourbachiste agenda.

Comment: I'm curious - aren't category theory and lambda calculus really two sides of the same coin? How do they lead to very different pictures of semantics?

Comment: Why aren't the LLM models on your list? In light of the recent impressive advances, I would think of these as the most successful and promising mathematical approaches to natural language.

Comment: Indeed, couldn't the spectacular success of LLMs reasonably be taken to show an essential inadequacy of many of the formal approaches to natural languages that you mention? One might find this to be fundamentally similar to what happened some time ago in AI generally, which had abandoned the formal/logical approaches to AI that were prominent in the very early days decades ago in favor of more successful essentially numerical stochastic methods.

Comment: To me, ***formalizing natural languages*** is an oxymoron.

Comment: Thank you, @JoelDavidHamkins for your comment. I should again preface the things I say with the fact that my understanding on both LLMs and formal approaches are shallow; but from what I understand, LLMs do not necessarily aim to provide a deeper understanding of the structure of language and its interaction with meaning. LLMs can generate text by associating and finding patterns between data points which while effective, was less interesting to me.

Comment: Although of course, the expectation that formal methods could offer said insight (for the users of language) into language, may be too naïve, and its truth is certainly up to debate (not to mention these two approaches are not entirely mutually exclusive from what I understand), but that was generally why I excluded AI-based methods in my post.

Comment: @WlodAA I suspect formalizing the interaction of people in a trade of goods, or the dialectic process of constructing of a proof, would have looked like similar oxymorons to people living one century ago, and yet here we are, with game theory, linear logic, and thinking sand.

Comment: @fosco, formalizing means freezing. (Now one can see that ***formalizing natural languages*** is an oxymoron),

Comment: @WlodAA yeah, the definition of formalization is "freezing" :D

Comment: Including LLMs in this post will make this question too broad and possibly outside the scope of MO. But how do we know that trained LLMs are not just performing a more formal approach? And we should be more concerned about consistency and safety than simply performance of language models. Will you get the same thing if you train two LLMs using the same training data but different initializations? If not, then we have room to improve the consistency of language models.

Comment: Regarding LLMs, Noam Chomsky and others have been rather outspoken in arguing that LLMs don't give us significant insight into natural language. Of course, plenty of people, such as [Steven Piantadosi](https://lingbuzz.net/lingbuzz/007180), have written scathing criticisms of Chomsky's approach. The situation is reminiscent of the [linguistics wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics_wars) half a century ago. Anyway, there is certainly no consensus that LLMs are better than, or incompatible with, other analytical approaches to natural language.

Comment: I, for one, would be ecstatic to belong to a group with Plato, Aristotle, and Russell.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, ha-ha-ha, good for you! (Why am I not surprised? :-))

Comment: Plato was quite good at pankration. I don't know how many people today could call him "pseudo-mathematician" to his face, and survive the experience

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I answered in Math.SE:

If you haven't read it already, I highly recommend reading L. T. F. Gamut's *Logic, Language, and Meaning*. If you already know some logic (say, up to first-order logic), the first volume may be a bit redundant (though the last two chapters, on pragmatics and the Chomsky hierarchy, may be new). The second volume, however, contains a very nice introduction to modal logic, type theory, and Montague semantics, as well as some other developments (such as Discourse Representation Theory). Obviously, it's just an introduction, but it is enough to give you an excellent overview of the subject.

Notice that many prominent semanticists in the Montague tradition (such as Barbara Partee) are also generativists, so you may need a background in Chomsky's theory to better understand their approach. There are a lot of books that work with this, but, for a general philosophical perspective, I quite liked John Collins's *Chomsky: A Guide for the Perplexed*, and, from a more technical one, Andrew Carnie's *Syntax: A Generative Introduction* (now in the 4th edition, together with the workbook). Incidentally, a classical textbook on this particular semantic approach is Heim & Kratzer's *Semantics in Generative Grammar*.

A quick observation about your summary: at least in my corner, Categorial Grammar **does not** refer to the application of Category Theory (the theory initially developed by Mac Lane and Eilenberg) to natural language. Rather, it refers to an approach that takes certain classes of expressions (*categories*, in the philosophical sense, since Aristotle) as basic and builds from them derived expressions. So a typical categorial grammar, for example, will take as basic expressions such as n (for names) and s (for sentences) and build derived categories of the form (n/s) (an expression that takes a name and builds a sentence, i.e. a predicate), (s, s/s) (an expression that takes two sentences and builds another sentence, i.e. a binary connective), etc. This type of grammar was developed in the 20s by Ajdukiewicz and later refined by Bar-Hillel in the 50s, and so was developed independently of Category Theory.

As for Montague, it is true that the introduction of the lambda calculus did revolutionize the field, but not by itself; the thing is that Montague showed how, by not trying to shoehorn everything into first-order logic (such as, say, Davidson was trying to do around the same time), and, instead, analyzing natural languages directly using more powerful and flexible means, one could produce an elegant compositional semantics for a remarkable fragment of natural language. (If you're interested in the history of the subject, several of [Partee's papers](https://people.umass.edu/partee/Research.htm) are relevant, and they can be very accessible---cf. [this one](https://semanticsarchive.net/sub2012/Partee.pdf), for instance.)

Comment: (I am a categorist.) Thanks for your answer. I associate Categorial Grammar with Joachim Lambek, whom I regard as a categorist (amongst other things.)

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow!

Answer (score 5):

This is a really a question about linguistics rather than mathematics, so you might be better off asking your question on [Linguistics StackExchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.  But anyway, I think what you're asking about is the field commonly known as [formal semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_semantics_(natural_language)).  I don't know a lot about this field, but you might start with the anthology *Formal Semantics: The Essential Readings*, edited by Paul Portner and Barbara Partee.  This will at least give you a historical perspective on the subject, which might help you decide what sub-area you want to focus on.